# Custom PHP Sort?

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I am trying to sort an array.

I have an array of data, where each line represents a new index in the array. I need to sort it descending, by the first number.

My array:

```
7[^.^]username[^.^]idnumber[^.^]State[^.^]
13[^.^] username[^.^] idnumber[^.^] State[^.^]
9[^.^] username[^.^] idnumber[^.^] State[^.^]
19[^.^] username[^.^] idnumber[^.^] State[^.^]
```

ksort and asort kind of work, but it recognizes a "9" as being bigger than "81", so it would return the following:

```
13[^.^] username[^.^] idnumber[^.^] State[^.^]
19[^.^] username[^.^] idnumber[^.^] State[^.^]
7[^.^]username[^.^]idnumber[^.^]State[^.^]
9[^.^] username[^.^] idnumber[^.^] State[^.^]
```

I know I need some kind of custom sort, but I'm not sure how. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of a PHP array is that? I see 16 faces in it. You should post the output of a `print_r` or `var_dump`...

Comment: You might be able to get away with a natsort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All PHP [`sort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) functions can take sort_flags as their second argument. Try using `SORT_NUMERIC`:

`sort($myArray, SORT_NUMERIC);`

Or use [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for a custom sorting callback

Comment: sort($myArray, SORT_NUMERIC); is perfect, but can I make it descending, rather than ascending?

Comment: array_reverse($array, true); could work, but I feel that it would be slow for large amounts of data.

Comment: Use [`rsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return (int)$a - (int)$b; });
```

This happens to work because casting "13[^.^] username[^.^]..." to an `int` will cut off anything after the first non-int character.

You should probably better pre-process your "array" though to separate that number value into its own array index.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a function called [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for creating user-defined sorting. It works be creating a comparison function which will return either 1, 0, or -1 depending on the two values being compared and how you define your logic.

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 5
4: 6
```